# How to get document by ID after insertion?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The idea is simple. User is adding a new document to collection and then wants to see it listed on the page without refreshing. I know I can sync all the dicuments with `onSnapshot`  but that is kind of a huge deal, right now I simply want to get the inserted document by `ID`.

```js
addWish = function() {
    let wish = document.getElementById("wish-text").value;
    if (wish && this.checkSignedIn()) {
        this.database.collection("wishes").add({
            wish: wish,
            author: this.user.name,
            date: 0 - Date.now(),
            voteup: 1,
            votedown: 0
        }).then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            this.database.collection('wishes').doc(docRef.id).get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
                this.renderWishes(documentSnapshots, 1);
            }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error getting document: ", error);
            });
         }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
```

Function `renderWishes` fails on one of the first lines. And then everything else fails too, for example `foreach`:

```
renderWishes = function(querySnapshot, type) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        let id = doc.id;
        doc = doc.data(); //and after I simply display data with templates ${doc.author}
```

> Error getting document:  TypeError: Cannot read
>   property '0' of undefined

And

> foreach`: "firebase.js:131 Error getting document:  TypeError:
>   querySnapshot.forEach is not a function

Is there any chance to fix this? Or it is impossible to get document by ID from Firestore?

Comment: The only instance of `querySnapshot` shown is in the `console.log()` call that's failing. Where do you define it exactly?

Comment: @Álvaro González updated. It is transferred to the function. And the way I know it actually works is because there is another function that renders all the documents on refresh correctly, but when I try to get one by ID I get an error.

Comment: It looks like you're missing some code.  The first line starts with .then().  What was the call just before it that generated the promise that you'd like to response to?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I skipped that because everything up to `console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);` worked perfectly and I saw that ID in the console. But I couldn't use it to get further. I updated the question with additional code. If you need any more I would provide more, I am not sure what exactly is needed. I thought the problem is obvious and lies somewhere in the middle, but this seems much more complicated...

Comment: I have a feeling that you're only accessing a single doc there. Can you try using `console.log(querySnapshot.data());` instead of `console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());` in your `renderWishes`?

Comment: Nothing really changed. Without any console output I am getting this error for "foreach": `firebase.js:131 Error getting document:  TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function` and to your code it replies: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`  and stops the code there. And that should be a single doc. I am trying to get one document with its own ID to download and display its information. Foreach there is created for other function to render 10 documents on page onload. But that's still not a problem. Query passes undefined for some reason...

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes the problem should be somewhere in the query. Right after refresh the other function already displays the new doc from DB but this thing refuses to download it with its own ID.But the other function simply lists docs by order: `this.database.collection("wishes").orderBy("date").limit(10);`.

Comment: Can you comment out the forEach for a while? Just to check if it prints the first log

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes you mean the whole foreach or just the operator? If only the operator then there is no point, `console.log`, that we just added, triggers error first(but I tried, though). Also I can't remove foreach to let code work by itself because this `querySnapshot.doc.data()` doesn't work, while I am doing this in a different way in foreach and it works there: `querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        let id = doc.id;
        doc = doc.data();` I have added those few lines to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the async [get()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentReference#get) operation is returning an object that's different than what you're anticipating in your code.

In your code, you're putting the following object into a new document:

```
    {
        wish: wish,
        author: this.user.name,
        date: 0 - Date.now(),
        voteup: 1,
        votedown: 0
    }
```

When you get() that document immediately after the add(), the variable you call `querySnapshot` is going to contain a [DocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentSnapshot) with exactly those contents in return.  DocumentSnapshot does not have a `docs` property, as you're trying to access.  That why you're getting an error about it being undefined.  DocumentSnapshot has an [id property](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentSnapshot#id) that will give you the id of the document you just fetched.

Comment: But what's the solution? `console.log(documentSnapshots);` output looks scary and contains a lot of stuff inside, while I can't get the stuff I need like `documentSnapshots.wish` or `documentSnapshots.doc.wish`. Also, the text in your answer is a bit strange so I could have missed the actual solution...

Comment: Sorry, I had some incorrect information there.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I can't get anything but id this way? So the only 2 ways to get that new message is by using `onSnapshot` or by HTTP functions? Or refresh.

Comment: Look at the documentation I linked for DocumentSnapshot to see what else it gives you.  There is a data() method that gives you the contents of the document.  That's kinda the whole point of doing a get().